# cucumber scenario and testng test cases XML 1-1 mapping

Tags: automated-tests, testng, integration-testing, cucumber-jvm

I need your help, I want to design Cucumber scenario that has 1-1 mapping with testng.

For example, If there are two feature file and one has 10 test scenarios in Cucumber and other has 2 test scenarios then I should be able to write 12 test cases name in testng XML and be able to execute them and able to report them.

Above method will enable me to execute only few scenarios at every run time by passing parameters in pom.xml.

Currently I have written below in testng xml file that further initiate cucumber-testng-runner and then it further calls to StepDefinition and feature file that may have 10 scenarios.

```
<test thread-count="5" name="TC001">
    <classes>
        <class name="testRunner.TestRunnernew" />
    </classes>
</test> <!-- TC001 -->
```

I want to write not only 1 test case in testng xml but 12 test cases as shown above in my testng xml so that I can parameter from POM.xml to execute only few scenarios

When I looked over internet, I found a similar issue already locked by someone for Cucumber JVM project

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/1113

I am not able to find the solution/implementation of problem though issue is closed now. May be because I am new to github?

Comment: Each scenario in cucumber-testng is run as a separate test. This is the behavior since 2.0.0. What is the cucumber version u are using? What is the need of writing test case names in XML? Why not use the cucumber testng runner for this?

Comment: Many Thanks Grasshopper for your response. May be I have not explained my problem correctly.Let me update my problem above. Also if i am failing to understand solution that you mentioned, please ping me at ankitsuhane@gmail.com so that i can connect with you over chat or any other way